audio_services Click on the background notification bar to enter the foreground
When playing in the background, I click the playback control in the notification bar to enter the foreground.
Which event can be monitored?
pubspec.yaml:
audio_service: ^0.18.13


Flutter doctor:
flutter version:
 Flutter (Channel [user-branch], 3.19.4, on macOS 14.1 23B74 darwin-arm64,
    locale zh-Hans-CN)
    ! Flutter version 3.19.4 on channel [user-branch] at
      /Users/a1/Downloads/flutter
      Currently on an unknown channel. Run `flutter channel` to switch to an
      official channel.
      If that doesn't fix the issue, reinstall Flutter by following instructions
      at https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install.
    ! Upstream repository unknown source is not a standard remote.
      Set environment variable "FLUTTER_GIT_URL" to unknown source to dismiss
      this error.
    • Framework revision 68bfaea224 (3 个月前), 2024-03-20 15:36:31 -0700
    • Engine revision a5c24f538d
    • Dart version 3.3.2
    • DevTools version 2.31.1
    • If those were intentional, you can disregard the above warnings;

however
  it is recommended to use "git" directly to perform update checks and
  upgrades.


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
